# By how, With how or Through how?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

I was thinking about this type of construction that is in *blank*:

> Oh my! I am amazed ____ you did this!

There is only three options to my head:

1. *By how*
2. *With how*
3. *Through how*

What is the difference between them? Furthermore, which one should I choose for that sentence?

Comment: You missed out [*amazed **at** how...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amazed+*+how&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Camazed%20%2A%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bamazed%20at%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20by%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20me%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20him%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20her%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20about%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20us%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20with%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20just%20how%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bamazed%20on%20how%3B%2Cc0), which is actually by far the most common preposition here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "I'm amazed by how you did this." - a good choice.
2. not as good.
3. not good.

Better yet:  "I am amazed at how you did this."

The sequence "by how" isn't a construction. The "by" actually is attached to "amazed".
So, you can be "amazed by" many things, and one of them is "how you did this".